# How to Pass variable value to Ansible tower from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, ansible-tower

I am trying to pass the variable value(extraVars) to Ansible tower from Jenkins but it returned variable name only not value.

My Jenkins code is

```
node ('windows'){
def zipFilename = "Windows file Zip (This value dynamically changed )"
stage('Deployment')
{
    
    wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', colorMapName: "xterm"]) {
    ansibleTower(
        towerServer: 'Ansible_Tower',
        jobTemplate: 'ANS- Test 1',
        templateType: 'job',
        importTowerLogs: true,
        jobType: 'run',
        removeColor: false,
        verbose: false,
        credential: 'cred',
        inventory: 'Ansible_Test',
        throwExceptionWhenFail: false,
        extraVars: '''---
        test_note: "${zipFilename}"'''
    )
}
}}
```

[Ansible Tower Output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/921ou.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, the only issue is that the parameter is not being evaluated because in groovy single quotes (`'''`) don't support string interpolation, only double quotes (`"""`) do.
So you only need to change the value used for `extraVars` to double quotes multi line string:

```
 extraVars: """---
 test_note: '${zipFilename}'"""
```

or the following if you need the double quotes:

```
 extraVars: """---
 test_note: \"${zipFilename}\""""
```

Comment: Also in tower you need to check the box under each variable you are using in jenkins. For example: if you click template > Select "credential" > you will be able to see a check box. Please select that